# with namemapping = 'Logical' was not found in the MetadataCache. in Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client

Tags: c#, dataverse

I am trying to use Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client tp query the users in CRM

The Code:

```
using (var client = new ServiceClient(cert, StoreName.My, null, instanceUri, true, null, clientId, null, null))
        {
            if (client.IsReady)
            {
                QueryBase query = new QueryExpression("systemusers?$select=systemuserid,domainname,internalemailaddress,fullname");
                var multiple = await client.RetrieveMultipleAsync(query);
```

Throws the Error:

> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
> (The entity with a name =
> 'systemusers?$select=systemuserid,domainname,internalemailaddress,fullname'
> with namemapping = 'Logical' was not found in the MetadataCache.
> MetadataCacheDetails: ProviderType=Dynamic, StandardCache=True,
> IsLoadedInStagedContext = False, Timestamp=9594795,
> MinActiveRowVersion=9594795, MetadataInstanceId=29692833,
> LastUpdated=2022-12-19 09:06:31.710,
> OrgId=09b2e10e-d67c-4ead-8c44-5e46d4ce9b5c)

I know the query is valid because I get results with REST call.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Maybe a better example?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the official Dataverse SDK (in your case Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client but this is also valid for the older Dynamics SDK) you can't write the QueryExpression using OData syntax.

The CRUD operators (including the QueryExpression that in combination with the RetrieveMultiple performs a Read) require a different syntax.

Following your example, the correct way is:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("domainname", "internalemailaddress", "fullname");
var multiple = await client.RetrieveMultipleAsync(query);
// multiple is a EntityCollection containing a Entities properties with the results
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a permissions issue. Make sure you have the correct permissions to access the entity you are trying to retrieve.

Just to confirm, the query works from REST call but that is not from within the same service where this call in?

Comment: That's right. REST call is as myself and ServiceClient is an app registration with certificate and delegated user_impersonation permission to Dynamics CRM. I did not see any other permission I can give. I don't think it is permission because I was able to send REST with the same ServiceClient and got JSON back.